# How do I create custom reference types in Doctrine ODM V1?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, odm

Is there any way to have a slightly custom reference (@ReferenceOne, @ReferenceMany)  in Doctrine MongoDB ODM?

For example, @ReferenceOneWithTs would keep a timestamp field to tell when the reference was created, or @ReferenceManyWithName will have a $name field for each reference, etc.

I think this can be achieved by embedding one or many custom ReferenceWithTs documents, with a timestamp field (for example), but if it's possible via annotations (a-la [Custom Field Types](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types)) it would be more elegant.

Comment: was cross-posted on the google groups, and answered there: "currently this is not supported". https://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/f197a7e048f337c5/eaaa8cd3f402acc4?show_docid=eaaa8cd3f402acc4